# Count down timer in microsoft word

Tags: ms-word

Microsoft word allows us to add datetime stamp which will update datetime and sync up with system datetime. I am looking for a similar item. Is there a countdown item available?

Usage: When I send a document to my colleague I mention this event will happen in 5 minutes.

```
Ex: I will kick the build in 5 minutes.
```

I am trying to express the same in the following way

```
Build will happen in 5:00 Minutes
```

after a second

```
 Build will happen in 4:59 Minutes
```

after five minute

```
Build will happen in 0:00 Minutes
```

or

```
Build happend
```

Does MSword capable of doing this?

Thanks,

Esen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no count down timer control kind of thing available. You have to write a macro to do that for you. Even if you use macro, unless the receipt user enable its content he wont see it. I would suggest use a javascript and send email with html body